# Java NIO isConnectable always return true

Tags: java, client-server, nio

I am doing client server Java program using Java NIO. Basically for the server codes, I took from [here](http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/694/). And for the client side, I took from [here](http://kramasundar.blogspot.com/2009/06/java-supports-nonblocking-io-since-java.html). Now it seems good. What I want to achieve now is send data from client to server,and server will send back to the client.

But I am having a problem with the logic. Lets say I put "AMessage", then I have to put "BMessage" in order to retrieve "AMessage" from the server. I did the debugging, and seems like my `key.isConnectable()` is always return `true`. I try to set the key interest, reregister it, but I didn't found any solution yet.

I have tried this one `key.interestOps(0);`, `myChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);`, but seems nothing happen. `isConnectable` still returned true. I found some issues informed by other people saying that it is localhost issue. I have no idea. But now I am running the server and client on localhost. Anyone has any idea?

Thanks :)

Edited: This is part of my codes:-

```
if (key.isConnectable()) {
if (myChannel.isConnectionPending()) {
    try{
        myChannel.finishConnect();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    System.out.println("Status of finishCOnnect(): " + myChannel.finishConnect() );
    System.out.println("Connection was pending but now is finished connecting.");
}

    ByteBuffer bb = null;
    ByteBuffer incomingBuffer = null;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  // Declare and Initialize the Scanner

    while (true) {

        System.out.println("Status isReadable is " + key.isReadable() + " and isWritable is " + key.isWritable() + 
                                            " and isConnectable is " + key.isConnectable());

        readMessage(key); //read if server send data


        //send data to server here
        String inputFromClient = input.nextLine(); //Get the input from client

        System.out.println("debugging after get input...");

        bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(inputFromClient.length()); //Allocate buffer size according to input size

        byte[] data = inputFromClient.getBytes("UTF-8"); //convert the input to form of byte
        bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(data); //wrap string inside a buffer

        myChannel.write(bb); //Write the buffer on the channel to send to the server
        bb.clear();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you please paste the code where the problem occured rather than asking us to navigate into the links

Comment: @gerrytan put the codes where the problem occurs. I supposed to skip the isConnectable once the connection is established, and go to `isReadable` or `isWritable` block. But now it is in the `isConnectable` block forever.

Comment: @gerrytan I tried to deregister the channel and reregister it and also change the interest key set in `isConnectionPending` block but seems not working.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve with `key.isConnectable()`? You didn't by any chance mistaken it as testing whether the client is connected to server using that method right?

Comment: @gerrytan Once connection is established, `isConnectable` will return true which is correct, after that I want to execute `isReadable` or `isWritable`. But since `isConnectable` always return true, I don't have any chance to execute code if the key is in read/write mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (key.isConnectable()) {
if (myChannel.isConnectionPending()) {
    try{
        myChannel.finishConnect();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    System.out.println("Status of finishCOnnect(): " + myChannel.finishConnect() );
    System.out.println("Connection was pending but now is finished connecting.");
}
```

There are several problems here.

1. The `isConnectionPending()` test is redundant. It must be pending, otherwise you wouldn't have got the event, but you may be tempting Providence by testing it. Get rid of this test.
2. You aren't doing the right thing with the `finishConnect()` call. If `finishConnect()` returns true *then* it is OK to deregister `OP_CONNECT` and register `OP_READ` or whatever. If it returns false, it isn't OK.
3. If `finishConnect()` throws an exception, the connect has failed and you must close the channel.
4. You are calling `finishConnect()` twice: once in the `try` block and once when logging the state. Get rid of the second call and use the result of the first call, if there is one. I would reorganize this to log (a) success from `finishConnect()`, (b) failure from `finishConnect()`, and (c) exception from `finishConnect()`, all separately.
5. Your final `System.out.println()` is just a lie in two out of the three cases. Don't tell yourself things that you don't know to be true. It just confuses the picture. Log each case separately as above.
6. You are assuming that the connection is readable, instead of testing `isReadable().`

Comment: thank you so much. Based on [this](http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/src/NioClient.java) structure, I modified my codes and use your advice. I have separate them. Made my codes more readable, now it seems works at the moment!

Comment: The code in the link isn't good enough by a mile. Specifically it doesn't address points (2) and (3) above correctly. Not even close.